# Studying Chemistry

Tags: stoichiometry, reference-request

I know this is a silly statement to say, but I really want to excel in Chemistry. The thing is, I forgot numerous things from elementary Chemistry such as introduction to basic stoichiometry.
Do you know any valuable study sites and books that I can study from beginning to advanced Chemistry?
Thanks.

Comment: Please open up a new question instead if you have one. Do not edit this question. It will invalidate community decision and the answers.

Answer (score 3):

Crash course science, which is run by Hank Green (renowned author John Green's brother) has proven quite useful to me, and I was using it up to the end of first year university. The only issue is that he talks incredibly fast, but you get used to it after a while.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FSyAehMdpyI&list=PL8dPuuaLjXtPHzzYuWy6fYEaX9mQQ8oGr

Answer (score 1):

In additional to the Crash Course YouTube channel as mentioned above, I would also recommend the chemistry videos submitted by Khan Academy. They're nicely detailed and very pertinent to first-year chemistry in college.